# Full height layout in nested view if parent is not height: 100%

Tags: css

I have a page, where I have a nested view in 5+ levels deep like

```
html* > body* > div* > div* > div* > div.container-fluid* > div.row > nav
```

The ones with an asterisk (`*`) doesn't have `height: 100%` defined on them, but for `nav` I would like to take the full height of the available space. Since the `nav` element's parents height's are only as tall as the content on the page, setting `height: 100%` doesn't result in a full height of the available space. What can I do about this besides

1. setting `height: 100%` on `html`, `body`, `div`, `div`, etc..
2. using `calc()` and/or `innerBoundsRect()` to calculate the height?

Thanks.

Comment: And what if the content is too large to fit in viewports full height?

Comment: If by available space you mean the entire viewport size, you can set `height: 100vh` on nav.

Comment: @DanM. available space in the OP situation would be `100vh - contentHeight`.